# what is pattern support in the TableGen Language

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am reading the [Writing An LLVM Backend](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html) but I can't find the meaning and definitions of "pattern support" (Pattern, Pat, PatFrag, PatLeaf, ComplexPattern).

Answer (score 3):

Read [The LLVM Target-Independent Code Generator](http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html) first. In particular, [this section about instruction selection](http://llvm.org/docs/CodeGenerator.html#selectiondag-select-phase) should answer your question.

E.g.:

> This phase takes a legal SelectionDAG as input, pattern matches the
>   instructions supported by the target to this DAG, and produces a new
>   DAG of target code.

It's a pretty long section with examples, so reproducing it fully here doesn't make much sense.

DAG matching is a topic that appears in many compiler texts and isn't LLVM specific.

For more LLVM specifics, and tablegen in particular, there's also [this resource](https://github.com/draperlaboratory/fracture/wiki/How-TableGen%27s-DAGISel-Backend-Works).

Comment: Thanks for the great link, but can you please specifically tell what a "complex pattern" really is? I mean at some place it includes [frameindex] as an operand, at other places it takes in [add, frameindex] as operands. The only thing I understand is that it is used to emit multiple output nodes. Is my understanding correct